# Rails 3 MySQL query question

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My **Job** model has **id** and **percentage** fields (among others).
**percentage** may be `nil`.

I would like to set a default **percentage** here:

```
class JobsController
  def new
    ...
    @job.percentage = <what should be here?>
    ...
  end
end
```

It should be calculated like this:

- Take the percentage of the latest job (a job with max **id**), which **percentage** isn't `nil`.
- If there are no jobs, or all jobs **percentage** is `nil`, it should be 23.

What is the easiest method to calculate this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably do this in your `Job` model:

[Update]

Added a test for `new_record?` in the callback, since percentage can legitimately be `nil`; we don't want to override it if it's been previously set as such.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :calculate_default_percent

  # other stuff

  private

    def calculate_default_percent
      if self.new_record?
        conditions = { :conditions => "percentage NOT NULL" }
        self.percentage = Job.last(conditions).nil? ? 23 : Job.last(conditions).percentage
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a named scope for finding recent record according to your need.

```
named_scope :recent, :conditions => "percentage != '' && 
             percentage IS NOT NULL", :order => 'ID DESC', :limit => 1

####Before Save

def calculate_default_percent
  record = Job.recent.first
  self.percentage ||= (record.nil? ? 23 : record.percentage)
end
```